# Filtering users who have more than x amount of nan values in a given column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to return a filtered list of all users who have more than n amount of nan values in a given column

so for example, assuming i have this dataset

```
name     val
 g       nan
 a       nan
 v       nan
 v       nan
 v       nan
 a       nan
 a       nan
 c       nan
```

In this case assuming n is 3. Meaning i want to get a list of names where val is nan 3 or more times

The desired outcome for this example would be:

```
name    val
 a      nan
 a      nan
 a      nan
 v      nan
 v      nan 
 v      nan
```

I know how to filter for nan values but not sure how to carry this particular task out

Comment: To filter and count, you may use the method in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472706/pandas-filter-counts

Comment: how about `df[df['val'].isna().groupby(df['name']).transform('sum')>=3]` ? just replace `3` with `n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution is to replace `na` with 1, and do groupby and filter.

## edit

create subset with .isna()

example code is

```
df2 = df[df['val'].isna()].fillna(1).groupby('name').sum()
df2[df2['val'] >= 3].reset_index()
```

which gives you the following output

```
   name val
0   a   3.0
1   v   3.0
```